# Youtube Analytics Reporting API: Empty Video Id for User Activity Report

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, youtube-api

I'm downloading the report `channel_basic_a1` mentioned at [Video Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports#video-reports). Some of the entries (i.e. 28 of 2k records) have the `video_id` as blank. Is this an error? or maybe there is some interpretation. I expect them not to be blank as they are video reports.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the exact reference, but the rows with `video_id` as blank are summary rows for the given dimensions but for all videos.